# Form API placeholder attribute rendered as "- Select -"

Tags: 8, forms

In a custom Drupal 8 module, I have a couple of Form API fields of `'#type' => 'select'`:

```php
    $form['form-right']['field_role'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Role'),
      '#title_display' => 'invisible',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#options' => [
        'foo' => $this->t('Role Foo'),
        'bar' => $this->t('Role Bar'),
        'baz' => $this->t('Role Baz'),
        'quux' => $this->t('Role Quux'),
        'plugh' => $this->t('Role Plugh'),
        'xyzzy' => $this->t('Role Xyzzy'),
      ],
      '#attributes' => [
        'placeholder' => $this->t('Role'),
      ],
    ];

    $form['form-right']['field_contact_reason'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Contact Reason'),
      '#title_display' => 'invisible',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#options' => [
        'foo' => $this->t('Contact Reason Foo'),
        'bar' => $this->t('Contact Reason Bar'),
        'baz' => $this->t('Contact Reason Baz'),
        'other' => $this->t('Other'),
      ],
      '#attributes' => [
        'placeholder' => $this->t('Contact Reason'),
      ],
    ];
```

Before a value is selected, the dropdown select picklists display the string `'- Select -'`:

[image: Form API placeholder attribute rendered as "- Select -"]

The client would like them to display the value in the placeholder attribute instead.

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Does the - Select - thing happen on all browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Select.php/class/Select

> **#empty_option**: (optional) The label to show for the first default option. By default, the label is automatically set to "- Select -" for
> a required field and "- None -" for an optional field.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!